# Can you safely use retired ropes for belaying children?

Tags: safety, rock-climbing, ropes, belaying, children

Climbing ropes are UIAA rated for so many falls of an 80kg weight. After that number of falls–or a specific period of time based on amount of use–you are supposed to retire the rope.

But what if the person you are belaying is only 15kg?

When ropes pass their recommended retirement age it doesn't exactly render them useless, but if you're using a rope to belay weights more than 80% less than what it's rated for, does that mean the rope will be good for a period of time 80% longer than recommended?

In my mind, a 15kg kid using a 9.8mm rope would be the equivalent of an 80kg man using a 22.6mm rope, which would last close to forever, but you probably wouldn't want to take any big falls with it.

To what weight can you safely use retired ropes for belaying small children on top-roped climbs?

Comment: Safe for you as the belayer, yes. Personally, not a path I'd go down myself. The next question becomes when might it no longer be safe. Just use a not-retired rope.

Comment: Related: [When should I retire my rope](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5270/when-should-i-retire-my-rope)

Comment: The strength of a rope is proportional to its cross-sectional area, not its diameter. So if you're going to talk about equivalent diameter based on climber weight, the equivalent diameter for an 80kg climber would actually be 22.6mm, since (22.6^2)/(9.8^2) = 80/15.

Comment: Are they your children?

Comment: @davidbak Not always. I use old ropes as back-up belays for kids I'm teaching how to rappel.

Comment: @DavidScarlett Thanks for that, I don't math very well all the time. I'm going to edit my number in my question.

Comment: Remember it's not just about strength - if a rope has the wrong elasticity, it can make a fall more harmful (either due to insufficient impact absorption, or due to a longer fall hitting something).  So make sure you find out whether this important property is retained in your "retired" rope.

Comment: @TobySpeight yes, but he is belaying from the top. In caves we only use static ropes. Even for belaying on ladders and downclimbs and it is fine for this purpose. We don't have any dynamic ropes in caves unless we do difficult free climbing upwards (very unusual).

Comment: "80 kg" is a mass, not a weight.

Comment: @Olin: yeah, good point, so the higher you climb or lower your latitude, the older your ropes can be, because g is reduced (and more significantly, effective-g with fictive centrifugal force subtracted). Why don't they put that in the manual? ;-)

Comment: @Shem: "80% less than what it's rated for, does that mean the rope will be good for a period of time 80% longer" -- *never* think that way, especially where safety tolerances are concerned. Not everything stands in a linear relation to everything else!

Comment: @Steve: The effect you cite is miniscule.  I was referring to outright wrong use of units.

Comment: @Olin: It's about 0.7%, and the variation in g is a precise measurement of the extent to which your pedantry is not absurd ;-) On earth, you can use mass to state weight.

Comment: Hey @OlinLathrop, what do Liberia, Myanmar, and the USA have in common? They are the *only* countries in the world that have not officially adopted the metric system. I have my **weight** on my drivers license in **kg**.

Comment: @Shem: Actually, the metric system has been legal in the US for a long time.  Yes, I know that mass and weight are often confused, even on official documents like drivers licenses, but that doesn't make it right.  The correct MKS unit for weight is the Newton, although the drivers license should simply state your *mass* in kg.  Weight is a force, which is really what rope strength is rated in.  The same rope on the ISS would still have the same strength rating in Newtons, but a kg rating would make no sense.

Comment: @OlinLathrop "...the metric system has been *legal* in USA..." what does legal mean? Was it illegal to use it before? No one in any metric country measures their weight in newtons.

Comment: The point is most of the time you are really measuring mass, for which kg is a correct unit.  The problem is when you call that "weight".

Comment: @OlinLathrop No one from a metricised country has any issues with calling kg "weight". Yes it is a measure of mass, but on Earth, we measure kg's by **standing on a scale**, ergo weight.

Comment: This question appears based on an incorrect premise, namely that ropes are supposed to be retired after reaching their rated number of falls.  This misunderstands the testing and is likely to result in the excessive retirement of perfectly good ropes.

Answer (score 15):

There is a little bit information out there ([here](http://itrsonline.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Weber-Hudson1999_ITRSPaper.pdf)), about falls of climbers *heavier* than normal which suggests (very roughly) almost a linear relationship between fall load (force) and body weight, assuming equal fall factor. Applying this in the reverse, a significantly lighter climber would apply a significantly smaller load.

[This](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/508/8864) says a UIAA fall is rated for a factor of 1.77.

Children of 15 kg don't climb lead (I'd say). During top roping, forces are *much* less, so I'd say it is safe, **if the rope passes visual inspection and "feels" otherwise "right" (e.g. no broken core)**.

I'd apply a rough safety margin of about 1 order of magnitude, so I'd say it's okay for people of up to 30-35 kg when top roping, and not okay for someone heavier or when lead climbing.

**In the end you have to use your own judgement, and if there are any doubts, just take the safer alternative: use a fresh rope.** Pieces of old rope are reusable as donations for e.g. childrens day cares.

Answer (score 9):

This is a really difficult question to answer in the abstract. The [UIAA](http://theuiaa.org/documents/safety/About_Ageing_of_Climbing_Ropes.pdf) claims that

> Ageing  caused  only  by  storage  can almost  be  neglected  compared  with ageing  during  use.  This  also  holds  for ageing  by  the  influence  of  ultraviolet radiation;  ropes  may  lose  their  colour with  time,  but  virtually  no  loss  of strength (more precisely, no loss of energy absorption capacity over an edge).

The answer then depends on why you have retired your rope. Ignoring retirement due to either a single *large* (high impact factor) fall or exposure to chemicals (e.g., battery acid), the rope has likely been retired due to wear (fraying of the sheath or flat spots) or some predetermined life span rule that you created or borrowed.

I don't like climbing on ropes that have flat spots. My ropes tend to get flat spots near the ends where the falls occur. Most of the routes I climb are longer, and therefore once I am forced to cut off a short section from the end, I retire the rope from lead climbing. I tend to then top rope on that rope until I wear out another lead rope. I cannot recall the last time I didn't have extra ropes for top roping.

My general rule for top roping is the rope needs to have a visually intact sheath (wear is fine) and not have any flat spots or bulges. It also cannot be ridiculously dirty (although I tend to climb in cleaner areas).

Answer (score 5):

TL;DNR: If you have a safety problem climbing with children, it won't be because the rope is a bit old.

You need to define what you mean by 'Safely'. I put it that is impossible as it varies for everyone on a daily basis. This makes it one of those unanswerable questions.

However, if you rephrase the question - move the focus from just the rope - "Is a retired rope safe" to taking kids climbing as a whole- 'How much does using a retired rope increase the danger of taking children climbing' you get to question that has a useful answer.

The other answers focus on the safety of a retired rope. The difference in safety between a brand new rope and retired rope (as in 'recently retired because of standards and manufacturer recommendations' rather than damaged or had a big fall) appears small and insignificant compared to the other dangers.

So, given the dangers of climbing, I suggest using a retired rope is extremely unlikely to create or contribute to an adverse outcome for any climber, and significantly less so for child or top roped climbers. What this means for Top roped and children can only become insignificant.

All of the above being said, there is another aspect at play that will override all this common sense. If you do take children climbing on say a 30 year old rope, what will people think and say of you? Will you be treated as a cautious climber who has thought through the implications and understands and manages the risks very well, or will you be labeled an irresponsible cowboy idiot who should not be allowed near children. If you had an accident, say a child unties his harness half way up the climb for a laugh, the 30 year old rope would be used to hang you, no matter how irrelevant it was to the situation.

Answer (score 5):

My rule of thumb is, if you have to ask if something is still safe to use, the answer is always **no**.

We all try to minimize risk and maximize cost/benefit. When I was younger and had less disposable income, my self answer to 'safe vs cost' questions was often more heavily weighted towards cost.  You can make these decisions multiple times and save lots of money, but the cost of that one time that safety should have been more heavily weighted, far exceeds all the money you saved in the earlier choices.

We each make and have to live with our own decisions.  The follow-up question you need to ask yourself, is can I live with the cost of being wrong about this choice?

Answer (score 2):

We have several "retired" ropes because we no longer trust them to take 2 factor leader falls. I repelled on one of them years after it was retired. If your ropes are like mine, they'll be fine for top-roping of most adults.

On the other hand, one rope we retired due to a rock fall landing on it. Nobody's climbing on that anymore. (We cut it in two where the rock landed, and it gets used for knot tying practice now.)

We've been kinda skirting the edge of the 10 year rule for a leader rope. Somehow we believe that a rope not for lead climbing is good for something like 10 more years after that before we really retire it. But on the up side, we buy over-diameter ropes in the first place so they should last a bit longer.

On the other hand, I looked at the rope that took two leader falls in one season, and at the end of the season I said to myself, "Hmm, time to retire that." Then the rock got it anyway.

Comment: "the rock got it" - don't know what that means

Comment: @MartinF: The one the rock caused us to cut in half in the previous paragraph.

Comment: The 'max age' rule for soft gear is 5 years - hard gear is 10 years. You should not be using any climbing rope for 10 years, let alone 20.

Comment: In case somebody's wondering about our gear, we inspect every piece of gear that will be used that year every spring when we haul the gear out of storage for the first climb of the year.