# Is there a way to find out the age of climbing ropes?

Tags: climbing, ropes

I have two half ropes from Camp that are basically unused, but are slowly getting old, and I would like to know their age. Is there a way to do that?

I know the name of the model: Camp Plekton 8.2mm. And I also know the batch number.

Edit:
These are my own ropes, so I do know how they were used, this is not the problem. The problem is that I am not 100% sure when I bought them. Could be 6 years ago, could be 8 years ago. Still within 10 years limit, but a big difference on how long they still could be fine to use. I also don't know how long they could have been stored in the shop.

Comment: Related [When should I retire my rope](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/5270/4079) I am on the fence about suggesting this new question is a duplicate.  I feel like if you don't know there age and it is important, it has been long enough that it doesn't matter. If you life is going to depend on them, don't use them,  If not keep them until they break.

Comment: Never use old ropes that you don't know the history of. Old or no you have no idea where these have been stored, what falls they've taken, etc. You say `basically unused`, you really can't know this.

Comment: @Liam I do really know this: they are my ropes bought by me in the shop. Stored in a plastic bag in a dry dark place, used max 3 times, taken 0 falls (:

Comment: Ah ok. That's fine then

Comment: Bearing in mind that you're betting your life that the batch number has been correctly logged by the company, I'd probably stick with the adage; *if you have to ask, buy a new one*. This also works for canned food.

Answer (score 37):

In the end I have contacted the manufacturer, and received a detailed answer surprisingly quickly.

So turns out, that the last 2 digits of the batch number are the year of manufacture. E.g. ABCD987612 --> Year of manufacture is 2012.

Additional useful information from the e-mail:

> The potential lifetime of this product in use is 10 years.
>
> Attention: This is only a potential lifetime, a rope could be
>   destroyed during its first use. It is the inspections which determine
>   if the product must be scrapped more quickly. Proper storage between
>   uses is essential. The lifetime of the rope in use must never exceed
>   10 years. The total maximum lifetime (storage before use + lifetime in
>   use) is thus limited to 12 years.

What I did not know is that I did not have to worry about the storage time in the shop. The two years are not included in the max 10 years of use.

Comment: That's security theater: Why should shelf time in shop be fine for exactly 2 years and shelf time at home suddenly set off a counter. There's certainly some aging, but all literature I read (e.g. Pit Schubert :) ) indicate that an undamaged (and use damages) rope is safe regardless of age.

Comment: it is most likely true, but with some things I would better be safe than sorry, climbing safety equipment is one of them (:

Comment: Having the batch number makes a big difference here; it saves you sacrificing the end of your rope to take apart for the identification tape!

Comment: @imsodin I don't know, but I think it means, 10 years after first use, without regard for store or home.  But not to exceed 12 years, even if you wait 6 years to use it the first time.

Comment: I was thinking maybe the stores have 2 years to sell the rope? But I am not sure :)

Comment: @imsodin everything interacts with our atmosphere ... iron rusts; rubber hardens and rope will likely lose its elasticity and become more likely to snap with sudden tension.  The estimate of 12 years life time is obviously just covering the manufacturers back but the point is that nothing is immune from degradation; and while it might be 20 or 50 years that it's likely good for, the cost if you get it wrong is death - and they're only willing to promise 10 years.

Comment: @UKMonkey it is not magic. One could ask what specific model (and corresponding assumptions) for the decay is used.

Comment: @jfs never said it was magic - but it is going to be random; and you can ask for the model but there's no requirement for them to tell you.

Answer (score 22):

The only way I know of would to be to [cut a small section off](https://www.climbing.com/skills/cutting-a-rope/) of one of the ends and then dissect it.

Inside of the sheath next to the core strands should be a **tracer thread and identification tape,**

> During the braiding process, an **identification tape
>   and tracer thread indicating the year of manufacture
>   are woven into the rope core.**
>
> The year of manufacture tracer thread is made from
>   polyamide, and is in a particular colour. Its colour
>   shows the year the rope was manufactured, although the same set of colours is repeated every ten
>   years. The year of manufacture tracer thread means
>   that this information is permanently marked for the
>   lifespan of the rope.
>
> The identification tape is a thin strip of polypropylene. In accordance with the EN 1891 standard
>   for static ropes, it has to display the following information: name of manufacturer, standard and rope type, year of manufacture and the type of material
>   the static rope is made from.

[Source](https://www.honor-safety.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Static-Ropes-Handbook_Kernmantellijn-HONOR-exclusief-distributiepartner.pdf)

The identification tape should say the year right on it, and I have seen this before when I was decoring retired climbing rope to make rope bracelets out of it.

You would have to contact the manufacturer in order to find out what year that color of tracer thread was used.

Comment: Whilst this is all true (and useful information generally), the term *half ropes* in the question implies dynamic rope rather than static.  How much of this answer is also applicable to *dynamic* rope?

Comment: @TobySpeight http://www.mytendon.com/dynamic-ropes-manual